# How to Remove multiple items in List using RemoveAll on condition?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I tried like following.

```
MyList.RemoveAll(t => t.Name == "ABS");
MyList.RemoveAll(t => t.Name == "XYZ");
MyList.RemoveAll(t => t.Name == "APO");
```

Instead how can I do something like:

```
MyList.RemoveAll(t => t.Name == "ABS" || t => t.Name == "XYZ" ||t => t.Name == "APO");
```

Comment: What does this have to do with LINQ to SQL? You're using `List<T>`, presumably...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You only need *one* lambda expression - the `||` goes within that:

```
MyList.RemoveAll(t => t.Name == "ABS" || t.Name == "XYZ" || t.Name == "APO");
```

In other words, "Given a `t`, I want to remove the element if `t.Name` is ABS, or if `t.Name` is XYZ, or if `t.Name` is APO."

There's only one "given a `t`" in there, which is what the `t =>` part means, effectively.

Answer (score 29):

A more extnsible approach would be to have a List for what to remove then

```
List<T> toRemove = ...
MyList.RemoveAll(t =>  toRemove.Contains(t.Name));
```

where T is a string in your example

Answer (score 7):

or

```
var nameToRemove = new[]{"ABS", "XYZ", "APO"};
MyList.RemoveAll(t => nameToRemove.Contains(t.Name))
```

Comment: Do you really want to construct a new array on every iteration?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Could you expand on your comment about a new array on every iteration?  Do you mean that it's iterating through `MyList` to perform the `RemoveAll`, and for each element in `MyList` it's creating a new copy of the `nameToRemove` array?

Comment: @SimonTewsi: I strongly suspect that the post originally had `MyList.RemoveAll(t => new[]{"ABS", "XYZ", "APO"}.Contains(t.Name))`, and that the author fixed it within the 5 minutes grace period which doesn't leave an edit history.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not required at any time that there are multiple items in the list, you should consider using a `HashSet` instead of `List`