# Is it possible to remove multiple items from the collection at a time?

Tags: c#

I need to remove multiple items from any collection like `List<>` or `ObervableCollection<>`. Using below methods, able to remove only one row at a time,

```
Collection.Remove(object value)

Collection.RemoveAt()
```

So, is any method or way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remove multiple items in List using RemoveAll on condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780671/how-to-remove-multiple-items-in-list-using-removeall-on-condition)

Comment: Check this MSDN link for RemoveAll functionality https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet removes 2 items starting at the 3rd position.

List.RemoveRange(3, 2);

Or if you arleady have the values which you want to remove you can do something like this

List.RemoveAll(t => t.Name == "Value1" || t.Name == "Value2" || t.Name == "Value3");

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions. It is better to point them to the already existing question